# How to center the Clicked position in the Recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I want to center the clicked position in the `Recyclerview`. I am able to scroll the `Recyclerview` to certain position but i want to middle that position in the screen.
I used this method to scroll to that position.

```
videoRecyclerview.scrollToPosition(position);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

if you use linearlayoutManager, you can use this code,

```
linearLayoutManager.scrollToPositionWithOffset(2, 20);

(linearLayoutManager.void scrollToPositionWithOffset (int position, 
            int offset))
```

Setting the offset to 0 should align with the top

Answer (score 25):

If you are using a **RecyclerView** and **LinearLayoutManager** this will work:

```
private void scrollToCenter(View v) {
    int itemToScroll = mRecyclerView.getChildPosition(v);
    int centerOfScreen = mRecyclerView.getWidth() / 2 - v.getWidth() / 2;
    mLayoutManager.scrollToPositionWithOffset(itemToScroll, centerOfScreen);
}
```

Comment: Please try to avoid just dumping code as an answer and try to explain what it does and why. Your code might not be obvious for people who do not have the relevant coding experience. Please edit your answer to include [clarification, context and try to mention any limitations, assumptions or simplifications in your answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: What is View v?

Comment: v is item view in adapter. This func works like a charm! You can call it for example from on item click listener

Comment: What if I want to use it onCreate?What will be v as View then? How to scrollToPosition of recyclerView item to center?

Comment: @Ispam it took few hours to understand how to calculate offset thanks to your answer it saves few.. :)

Comment: Upvote for the peachiest and the best working answer, thanks man

Comment: how to get the instance of itemView?

Answer (score 7):

first move scroll to your item, but whenever recyclerView scrolls it just brings the item in visible region, it is never sure that the item is in center or not, so we find the center item and then check if we are on next to center to item or behind it, here is working logic

```
recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(index);
int firstVisibleItemPosition = rvLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
int lastVisibleItemPosition = rvLayoutManager.findLastVisibleItemPosition();

int centerPosition = (firstVisibleItemPosition + lastVisibleItemPosition) / 2;

    if (index > centerPosition) {
        recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(index + 1);
    } else if (index < centerPosition) {
        recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(index - 1);
    }
```

Comment: In case of a horizontal recyclerView with images, this solution isn't perfect. It fails to center when the clicked item is not near the center already. @Ispam's solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/44854796/860311 works perfect though

Comment: have to add if validation for dont giving index crash , if index!=0, thx..

Answer (score 7):

If you need **smooth scroll to centre** for LieanerLayoutManager both horizontal & vertical

Copy the entire code and simply call** `scrollToCenter`:

```
public void scrollToCenter(LinearLayoutManager layoutManager, RecyclerView recyclerList, int clickPosition) {
    RecyclerView.SmoothScroller smoothScroller = createSnapScroller(recyclerList, layoutManager);

    if (smoothScroller != null) {
        smoothScroller.setTargetPosition(clickPosition);
        layoutManager.startSmoothScroll(smoothScroller);
    }
}

// This number controls the speed of smooth scroll
private static final float MILLISECONDS_PER_INCH = 70f;

private final static int DIMENSION = 2;
private final static int HORIZONTAL = 0;
private final static int VERTICAL = 1;

@Nullable
private LinearSmoothScroller createSnapScroller(RecyclerView mRecyclerView, RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager) {
    if (!(layoutManager instanceof RecyclerView.SmoothScroller.ScrollVectorProvider)) {
        return null;
    }
    return new LinearSmoothScroller(mRecyclerView.getContext()) {
        @Override
        protected void onTargetFound(View targetView, RecyclerView.State state, Action action) {
            int[] snapDistances = calculateDistanceToFinalSnap(layoutManager, targetView);
            final int dx = snapDistances[HORIZONTAL];
            final int dy = snapDistances[VERTICAL];
            final int time = calculateTimeForDeceleration(Math.max(Math.abs(dx), Math.abs(dy)));
            if (time > 0) {
                action.update(dx, dy, time, mDecelerateInterpolator);
            }
        }


        @Override
        protected float calculateSpeedPerPixel(DisplayMetrics displayMetrics) {
            return MILLISECONDS_PER_INCH / displayMetrics.densityDpi;
        }
    };
}


private int[] calculateDistanceToFinalSnap(@NonNull RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager, @NonNull View targetView) {
    int[] out = new int[DIMENSION];
    if (layoutManager.canScrollHorizontally()) {
        out[HORIZONTAL] = distanceToCenter(layoutManager, targetView,
                OrientationHelper.createHorizontalHelper(layoutManager));
    }

    if (layoutManager.canScrollVertically()) {
        out[VERTICAL] = distanceToCenter(layoutManager, targetView,
                OrientationHelper.createHorizontalHelper(layoutManager));
    }
    return out;
}


private int distanceToCenter(@NonNull RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager,
                             @NonNull View targetView, OrientationHelper helper) {
    final int childCenter = helper.getDecoratedStart(targetView)
            + (helper.getDecoratedMeasurement(targetView) / 2);
    final int containerCenter;
    if (layoutManager.getClipToPadding()) {
        containerCenter = helper.getStartAfterPadding() + helper.getTotalSpace() / 2;
    } else {
        containerCenter = helper.getEnd() / 2;
    }
    return childCenter - containerCenter;
}
```

Comment: This is the perfect answer! Btw there is a type `DIAMENTION`

Comment: its misspell , try this DIMENSION

Comment: It does work at least if I removed the if checks CanScrollVertically(). Sometimes there are some flashing issues, but at least it is functional, thanks for posting

Comment: Just “import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearSmoothScroller;”  which contains "mDecelerateInterpolator" 

or you can create your own one:

"protected final DecelerateInterpolator mDecelerateInterpolator = new DecelerateInterpolator();"

Answer (score 2):

it's worked for me with this code :

```
 layoutManager.scrollToPositionWithOffset(pos - 1,0);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
//on the click callback 
    view.OnClickListener { callback?.onItemClicked(it)}        



// code in activity or your fragment
override fun onItemClicked(view: View) {
  val position = recyclerView.getChildLayoutPosition(view)
  recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(position)
}
```

Answer (score -2):

simplest hack ever, this was good enough for me:

```
videoRecyclerview.scrollToPosition(position+2);
```

if position+2 is within the arraylist.

Comment: I tried all the answers above, and nothing worked for me except this. Thank you Alberto.